# How to install Debian on an encrypted lvm located on RAID using Intel Rapid Storage Technology?

Tags: linux, debian, installation, raid, disk-encryption

I was preparing the PC-based NAS system. The system uses 4 HDs in RAID 5 configuration.
I wanted the system to boot also from RAID, so I have selected a motherboard supporting the Intel Rapid Storage Technology. The RAID Volume was created in BIOS, after enabling that function.
The installation was performed from the Debian stable (bullseye) netinst iso image in expert install mode.
During the installation, before partitioning of the disks I had to activate the second console and manually run:

```
mdadm -Asv
```

After that the installer started to see the RAID (`/dev/md126`), and I could:

1. Create the ESP (`/dev/md126p1`) and boot (`/dev/md126p2`) partitions.
2. Create the encrypted volume on `/dev/md126p3`.
3. Create LVM on the encrypted volume and volume group `mynas_vg` in it.
4. Create `swap`, `root` (for the system), and `data` (for the served directories) volumines in `mynas_vg` group.
5. Proceed with the installation of the system.

The installation went correctly. However, after the system got rebooted, I got a series of messages (some of them were repeated many times):

```
Volume group mynas_vg not found
Cannot process volume group mynas_vg
cryptsetup: Waiting for encrypted source device UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

finally the booting process got interrupted, and I got
`(initramfs)`
prompt. The system could not boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the problem even without using the installer's rescue mode.

At the `(initramfs)` prompt I ran:

```
IMSM_NO_PLATFORM=1 mdadm -Asv
```

After that the `/dev/md126` and its partitions became available.
Then I ran:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/md126p3 md126p3_crypt
```

The volume group `mynas_vg` started to be visible.
I have left the `(initramfs)` with `CTRL+D` and the system booted correctly.

In the started system, I edited the files in the `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-block` directory:

1. In the `cryptroot` file, I have changed:
   `PREREQ=""` into `PREREQ="mdadm"`
2. In the `mdadm` file, I have added the line:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   PREREQ="multipath"
   export IMSM_NO_PLATFORM=1 # <-- This line is added
   prereqs()
   {
        echo "$PREREQ"
   }
   ```

After the above modifications I ran:

```
update-initramfs -c -k all
```

Then I rebooted the system.
With so modified initial ramdisk the system boots correctly.
It displays three times the messages about unavailable `mynas_vg` group and once a message about waiting crypted source device, but then asks for the password to the md126p3_crypt disk, and after the password is entered, the system starts correctly.

Of course, in case of other raid parameters the name of the RAID device may be different than `/dev/md126`. If you want to follow my recipe, you must accordingly change that name and all other names derived from it.

Please remember, that update of the system may restore the original contents of the modified scripts. In case if your system stops booting, you may need to repeat the above procedure.